# how to choose a range for filtering points by RGB color?

Tags: colors, computer-vision

I have an image and I am picking colors by **RGB** (data sampling). I select **N** points from a specific region in the image which has the "same" color. By "same" I mean, that part of the image belongs to an object, (let's say a yellow object). Each picked point in the **RGB** case has three values **[R,G,B]**. For example: [120,150,225]. And the maximum and minimum for each field are **255** and **0** respectively.
Let's assume that I picked N points from the region of the object in the image. The points obviously have different **RGB** values but from the same family (a gradient of the specific color).

**Question:**
I want to find a range for each **RGB** field that when I apply a color filter on the image the pixels related to that specific object remain (to be considered as inliers). Is it correct to find the maximum and minimum from the sampled points and consider them as the filter range? For example if the max and min of the field **R** are 120 ,170 respectively, can it be used as a the range that should be kept.

In my opinion, the idea is not true. Because when choosing the max and min of a set of sampled data some points will be out of that range and also there will be some point on the object that doesn't fit in this range.

What is a better solution to include more points as inliers?

If anybody needs to see collected data samples, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I fully grasp what you are asking for, but in my opinion filtering in RGB is not the way to go. You should use a different color space than RGB if you want to compare pixels of similar color. RGB is good for representing colors on a screen, but you actually want to look at the hue, saturation and intensity (lightness, or luminance) for analysing visible similarities in colors.

For example, you should convert your pixels to HSI or HSL color space first, then compare the different parameters you get. At that point, it is more natural to compare the resulting hue in a hue range, saturation in a saturation range, and so on.

[Go here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Converting_to_RGB) for further information on how to convert to and from RGB.

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is that you implicitly try to reinvent either color indexing or histogram back-projection. You call it color filter  but it is better to focus on probabilities than on colors and color spaces. Colors of course not super reliable and change with lighting (though hue tends to stay the same given non-colored illumination) that's why some color spaces are better than others. You can handle this separately but it seems that you are more interested in the principles of calculating "filtering operation" that will do segmentation of the foreground object from background. Hopefully.

In short, a histogram back-projection works by first creating a histogram for R, G, B within object area and then back-projecting them into the image in the following way. For each pixel in the image find its bin in the histogram, calculate its relative weight (probability) given overall sum of the bins and put this probability into the image. In such a way each pixel would have probability that it belongs to the object. You can improve it by dividing with probability of background if you want to model background too.

The result will be messy but somewhat resemble an object segment plus some background noise. It has to be cleaned and then reconnected into object using separate methods such as connected components, grab cut, morphological operation, blur, etc.